# How to use a string prepared in a data frame in a loop as a string to name new data frames?

Tags: r, string, loops, for-loop

I am trying to use a string, I generated in a data frame, as a string variable in a loop. I would like to end up with (in this case) 10 data frames named as preparated in var1.1. But I have no idea how to do this.

```
var1 <- c(1:10)
my.data <- data.frame(var1,var1, var1) 
my.data[,2]<- paste("name")
my.data[,2] <- apply(my.data[,c(2,3)], 1, paste, collapse="")
my.data[,2] <- gsub(' ','_', my.data[,2])

my.data

   var1 var1.1 var1.2
1     1 name_1      1
2     2 name_2      2
3     3 name_3      3
4     4 name_4      4
5     5 name_5      5
6     6 name_6      6
7     7 name_7      7
8     8 name_8      8
9     9 name_9      9
10   10 name10     10

for(i in seq(along=length(my.data[,1]))){
  my.data[i,2] <- data.frame(my.data[i,1],my.data[i,3] )    
}
Warning message:
In `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, i, 2, value = list(my.data.i..1. = 1L,  :
2 Variablen angegeben, um 1 Variablen zu ersetzen
```

I would like to have something like this:

```
name_1 

var1    var1.2
1   1     1

name_2

var1    var1.2
1   2     2
```

Comment: No, put your data.frames together into a list. Then you can name them and they don't clutter the global environment and it is very easy to interate over list elements in subsequent steps.

Comment: There is a shorter way to build the second column `my.data[,2] <- paste0("name_", my.data[,2])`

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding correctly, you want a `data.frame` *inside* another structure. I am not sure that is possible in the way you present question, but here are some alternatives that might work (it is also possible I am misunderstanding, then here are a couple of options based on @Roland's comment):

Make a matrix of same number of rows, only 1 column (for each data.frame):

```
mat <- matrix(list(), nrow=nrow(my.data),ncol=(ncol(my.data) - 2))
#check how it looks like
mat
#     [,1]  
#[1,] NULL
#[2,] NULL
#[3,] NULL
#[4,] NULL
#[5,] NULL
#[6,] NULL
#[7,] NULL
#[8,] NULL
#[9,] NULL
#[10,] NULL
```

Then insert elements into the matrix with a loop (modified):

```
for(i in 1:length(my.data[,1])) {
  mat[[i,1]] <- data.frame(var1 = my.data[i,1], var1.2= my.data[i,3] )    
}
```

Check again the structure:

```
 mat
#     [,1]  
#[1,] List,2
#[2,] List,2
#[3,] List,2
#[4,] List,2
#[5,] List,2
#[6,] List,2
#[7,] List,2
#[8,] List,2
#[9,] List,2
#[10,] List,2
```

Every element of `mat` is populated by a `data.frame`:

```
> mat[1,1]
[[1]]
  var1 var1.2
1    1      1
> str(mat[[1,1]])
'data.frame':   1 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ var1  : int 1
 $ var1.2: int 1

> mat[10,1]
[[1]]
  var1 var1.2
1   10     10
> str(mat[[10,1]])
'data.frame':   1 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ var1  : int 10
 $ var1.2: int 10
```

An alternative option, is to put them inside of a list. Here is one way:

Make an empty list:

```
listy <- rep(NA,length(my.data$var1.1))
```

Check your object:

```
listy
# [1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

Populate:

```
for (i in 1:length(listy)) {
  listy[i] <- as.data.frame(my.data$var1.1[i])
  listy[[i]] <- data.frame(var1 = my.data[i,1], var1.2= my.data[i,3] )
}
```

Every element of the list is a data.frame:

```
listy[1]
[[1]]
  var1 var1.2
1    1      1
str(listy[1])
List of 1
 $ :'data.frame':   1 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ var1  : int 1
  ..$ var1.2: int 1
listy[10]
[[1]]
  var1 var1.2
1   10     10
str(listy[10])
List of 1
 $ :'data.frame':   1 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ var1  : int 10
  ..$ var1.2: int 10
```

Comment: I am sorry, I should have make it clearer, that I need these 10 data frames speratly. The dummy data in my question, is not the kind of data, I will use later. I know it is usually no good practice to clutter the environment...

Comment: Yeah, cluttering the environment is highly frowned upon in the community. @snaut's answer is what you are looking for (although the loop doesn't work, it needs editing), try this: `for(i in 1:length(my.data[,1])) {
  assign(my.data[i,2], data.frame(var1 = my.data[i,1], var1.2= my.data[i,3] )) 
}`

Answer (score 0):

Use the `assign` function to assign a value to a variable from a string variablename:

```
for(i in seq(along=length(my.data[,1]))){
  assign(my.data[i,2], data.frame(my.data[i,1],my.data[i,3] ))
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Assign works quite fine to name my data frame as I want it to be named. But the loop isn't working proberly. I need these 10 single data frames as names_1 to names_10. Do you have an idea, why this loop only produces one data frame, namely name_1?